# Разница между delete и operator delete

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

В чём разница между этими действиями?

```
static void operator delete (void *p)  { ::delete p; }
static void operator delete (void *p)  { ::operator delete(p); }
```

Кажется, что всё работает в обоих случаях: https://ideone.com/cQ8lTJ

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct a { static void operator delete (void *p)  { ::delete p; } };
struct b { static void operator delete (void *p)  { ::operator delete(p); } };

int main()
{
  delete new a();
  delete new b();

  cout << "Done :)" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Но если добраться до предупреждений компилятора https://ideone.com/bN3XOh

> ```
> prog.cpp: In static member function ‘static void a::operator delete(void*)’:
> prog.cpp:5:62: warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined [-Wdelete-incomplete]
>  struct a { static void operator delete (void *p)  { ::delete p; } };
>                                                               ^
> ```

то возникает ощущение, что он предупреждает о UB в первом варианте.

Действительно ли это UB?
Если да, то почему это всего лишь предупреждение, а не ошибка?

PS: Из похожего нашёл [такой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10573678/4928642), но там про внутреннее устройство вызова `delete`, причём не показывается, почему именно код из моего вопроса неверный.

Comment: ассемблерный код абсолютно одинаковый как ни странно. https://godbolt.org/g/74H1pB .

Comment: @pavel, да я вообще-то и думал, что это одно и то же, а компилятор почему-то говорит иначе)))

Comment: @AnT, вообще-то у меня в вопросе ссылка на ideone, где код не только скомпилировался, но и выполнился ожидаемым образом. а в комментарии выше показывается, что тоже компилируется, причём с ассемблерным кодом, который получается в результате. Так что твоё утверждение как минимум спорное.

Comment: Во-первых, ideone - это игрушечный компилятор, не только не имеющий никакого отношения к С++, но еще и нагло фильтрующий диагностические сообщения (!). Во-вторых, авторитет компилятора GCC в  умолчательной конфигурации  в качестве средства проверки корректности С++ кода - ниже плинтуса. "Скомпилировался в GCC" - не значит ничего вообще.

Comment: Я удалил свой комментарий, ибо вижу, что изначальное требование C++98 на полноту типа в `delete` в современном C++ было ослаблено и, похоже, полнота больше не требуется. Однако `delete` для `void *` в современном C++ - не определено.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70585/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy---delete--operator-delete).

Comment: Нет, я зря удалил свой комментарий. Даже в C++17 применять оператор `delete` к `void *` запрещено.  Тот факт, что GCC выдает на это "просто предупреждение" - это не боле чем очередная вольность GCC. Сlang с `-pedantic-errors` выдаст ошибку, а GCC даже с `-pedantic-errors` просто предупреждает... Безобразие.

Comment: @AnT, ну так может ответ напишешь подробный? PS: Комментарии, удалённые не модераторами, восстанавливать не могу.

Comment: Ответы Abyx и VladD все правильно объясняют.

Comment: @AnT, ни в одном из них не говорится, что должна быть ошибка компиляции. это утверждается только в твоём комментарии, который ты "зря удалил".

Comment: У VladD: "Таким образом, использование ::delete p; (первый вариант) запрещено стандартом, и ведёт таким образом к UB. Почему это объявлено UB, а не ошибкой компиляции, мне сложно судить."

Comment: @AnT, ну так UB означает, что программа компилируется без ошибок, запускается, а там уже делает что захочет. Ты же утверждаешь, что код  не должен компилироваться. Или уже не утверждаешь? Я запутался в твоих комментариях. И вообще, я чат для чего создал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator delete` - это функция.
`::operator delete(p);` - это вызов этой функции.

Выражение `delete p;` - это вызов деструктора, поиск указателя на полный объект и вызов функции `operator delete` для этого полного объекта.
Операция `delete` для `void*` не имеет смысла, о чем и говорит компилятор.
В контексте другой функции `operator delete` оно особенно не имеет смысла.

---

Более подробно про выражение `delete` и функции `operator delete` можно [почитать тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696464/177684).

Comment: _"оно особенно не имеет смысла"_ - не понял смысла этой фразы...

Comment: То есть, разница такая же, как и между `a + b` и `operator + (a, b)`?

Comment: Ага, понял, не дочитал ответ. То есть если для структуры данных нету переопределённого оператора `delete` (что обычно так и есть, правильно?), то этим просто освобождается память?

Answer (score 3):

В качестве небольшого дополнения к ответу @Abyx:

Согласно [стандарту](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#1), 8.5.2.5/1:

> The operand shall be of pointer to object type or of class type.
>   If of class type, the operand is contextually implicitly converted to a pointer to object type.⁸²
>
> ---
>
> ⁸²⁾ This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type `void*` because `void` is not an object type.

Таким образом, использование `::delete p;` (первый вариант) запрещено стандартом, и ведёт таким образом к UB. Почему это объявлено UB, а не ошибкой компиляции, мне сложно судить.

---

Ещё одна причина, по которой такой вызов проблематичен: ([стандарт](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3), 8.5.2.5/1):

> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Немного кода для иллюстрации ответа @Abyx'а

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo (const std::string &_str): str(_str) {
        std::cout << str << "::" << __func__<< '\n';
    }
    ~Foo () { std::cout << str << "::" << __func__<< '\n'; }
    static void* operator new (size_t sz) {
          std::cout << __func__<< " sz(" << sz << ')' << '\n';
          return ::operator new(sz);
    }
    static void operator delete (void* p) {
          std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; return ::operator delete(p);
    }
    std::string str;
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
    Foo *foo = new Foo("foo1");
    delete foo;

    std::cout << '\n';
    foo = new Foo("foo2");
    Foo::operator delete(foo);


    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
operator new sz(32)
foo1::Foo
foo1::~Foo
operator delete

operator new sz(32)
foo2::Foo
operator delete
```

т.е. Как и ожидается operator delete не вызывает деструктор.

Answer (score -2):

`::delete p;` и `::operator delete(p);` - две альтернативных записи вызова глобального оператора `delete`.

А предупреждение компилятора справедливо вызвано попыткой удаления указателя на незавершенный тип (incomplete type). Однако неопределенное поведение конкретно в этом случае заключается не в вызове `delete` именно для типа `void*` (хотя он и является незавершенным), а в том, что тип, на который указывает указатель, не является непосредственно типом или одним из подтипов типа, который был и использован при вызове оператора `new`, создавшего этот объект. Причем диагностического сообщения в этом случае вообще не требуется. Скорее всего, в компиляторе еще не реализовали дополнительные диагностики для вызова delete с использованием синтаксиса функции, так как такое встречается сравнительно редко.

Comment: Эм.. И как этот ответ объясняет предупреждение компилятора только на одну из них?

Comment: почему тогда в 1 случае есть предупреждение, во втором нету? g++ 7.2 точно воспроизводится.

Comment: @pavel Диагностического сообщения в этом случае вообще не требуется. Может дополнительное предупреждение сделано только для вызова `delete` с использованием синтаксиса оператора, а не как функцию.

Comment: Неверно. `::delete p;` и `::operator delete` - совершенно разные, независимые вещи. `::delete p` - это выражение с унарным оператором `delete` языка С++. Этот оператор поддерживает особый синтаксис - `::` перед `delete` - который является просьбой вызвать изнутри реализации этого оператора именно *глобальную* функцию освобождения сырой памяти `::operator delete`. А `::operator delete` - это глобальная библиотечная (или глобальная пользовательская) функция освобождения "сырой" памяти.