# Можно ли игнорировать пустого наследника при написании деструктора?

Tags: c++, наследование, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Как известно, при необходимости удаления через указатель на родительский класс, класс должен иметь виртуальный деструктор, чтобы оператор `delete` вызвал верный деструктор дочернего класса.

Меня же интересует случай, когда дочерний класс не добавляет к родительскому ничего, что следовало бы уничтожать. Например, вообще не добавляет никаких полей к базовому классу. Можно ли в таком случае проигнорировать правило виртуальности деструктора или даже в таком случае удаление будет UB?

Пример кода: https://ideone.com/B3Wx7m

```
struct A {
  int *p;
  A(unsigned n) : p(new int[n]) {}
  ~A() { delete [] p; }
};

struct B : A
{
  B() : A(4) {}
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new B();
  delete a;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попытка легализовать UB? Хе-хе

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В стандарте четко сказано, что такое удаление вызывает неопределенное поведение. Не делается никаких оговорок на тему того, добавлены ли какие-то поля в класс-наследник или нет.

> **5.3.5 Delete**
>   **3** In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. [...]

На деструктор класса также обычно накладываются (могут накладываться) какие-то неявные служебные функции, которые могут работать неправильно при вызове неправильного деструктора.

В частности, в типичной реализации на деструктор [возложена обязанность вызова правильной функции `operator delete`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590529/182825), которая может быть перегружена для каждого класса отдельно. То есть если бы в `struct B` была определена своя статическая функция `operator delete`, то без виртуального деструктора обеспечивать ее функциональность пришлось бы какими-то другими методами. (Авторы стандарта, скорее всего, и ориентировались именно на такую реализацию вызова перегруженного `operator delete`.)

Например

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{
  // virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : A
{
  static void *operator new(size_t s) 
    { return (char *) std::malloc(s * 2) + s; }

  static void operator delete(void *p, size_t s)
    { std::free((char *) p - s); }
};

int main()
{
  A* p = new B;
  delete p;
}
```

В популярных реализациях такой код упадет из-за вызова неправильного `operator delete`. Но достаточно добавить в `A` виртуальный деструктор, как все станет хорошо. Обратите внимание, что оба члена `B` - статические функции, то есть физически в `B` ничего не добавлено.

Comment: Ну в вопорсе предполагалось, что delete я тоже перегружать не собираюсь... Кстати, какие-то у тебя странные new и delete - у меня [в другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760847/178988) там параметра с размером не было...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вариант `operator delete`, в котором есть параметр с размером, поддерживается начиная с С++14. А насчет "предполагалось-не предполагалось"... Скрытые служебные функции, выполняемые деструктором, в языке не оговариваются. Это - не более чем пример одной из них. Могут быть и другие, которые пострадают от невиртуальности.

Comment: @Qwertiy, зачем добавлять в стандарт лишние ограничения, когда они не нужны (это я про тему вопроса)? Проще добавить один запрет, чем поддерживать каждый случай, который может прийти в голову.

Comment: @AnT На деструктор не возлагается правильность вызова никаких функций. Перегруженные функции и методы определяются на этапе трансляции и деструкторы в том числе, сам деструктор это специальный метод вызываемый в рантайме и соответственно ничего уже там не определяющий. Вы же дали цитату и добавили код ей не соответствующий, тут и перегруженные операторы не при чем, так как без виртуального деструктора однозначно неправильное удаление и UB. Хотя если убрать домыслы, то это ответ.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Вы вообще читали вопрос и мой ответ? Во-первых, описанная мною функциональность приведена здесь для того, чтобы показать автору, что функциональность виртуального деструктора не теряет своей ценности даже в том случае, когда класс-наследник не добавлял никаких новых полей. (Это - важная часть вопроса.) Во-вторых, мой ответ содержит только жесткие факты - именно так реализуют функциональность перегруженного `operator delete` существующие реализации С++. Более того, стандарт языка хоть и не предписывает именно такой подход к реализации, он тем не менее подогнан именно под него.

Comment: @AnT "в типичной реализации на деструктор возложена обязанность вызова правильной функции operator delete,"  это Вас не смущает?

Comment: В-третьих, я же ясно написал, что выбор перегруженного `operator delete` происходит именно *во время выполнения*, в соответствии с динамическим типом удаляемого объекта. Вы же нам пишете "перегруженные функции и методы определяются на этапе трансляции". Что это чушь? Если я написал, что выбор перегруженного на этапе трансляции в общем случае невозможен, значит он невозможен. Проверяйте, что пишете.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Нет не смущает - это именно так и есть :)) Еще раз повторяю: именно так это и делается во всех существующих реализациях С++. Другого способа пока не придумали. Посмотрите как-нибудь на досуге.

Comment: @AnT  ODR Вам в помощь.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: "ODR Вам в помощь": - это здесь к чему?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86161/discussion-between-andrey-sv-and-ant).

Comment: @AnT Почитайте на досуге.

Comment: @Andrey Sv: Так. Вы, я вижу, просто замусориваете обсуждение какой-то не относящейся к делу болтовней и терминами, которых вы не понимаете. Все вышенаписанное мною - к обязательному вызубриванию наизусть. Вежливые вопросы по теме - разрешаю, бессмысленное разглагольствование - запрещаю. Конец дискуссии.

Comment: @AnT Вы тут главный конечно, я сделал вежливое замечание, мне жаль, что Вас это расстроило...